# Can you identify these LEGO animals, mountains, and minifigs?

Tags: part-identification, set-identification

[image]

Came across this package 2 of a larger set. I could only upload several pieces of it. Can anyone identify this for me please?

Answer (score 6):

You have bag 2 of set [60014: Coast Guard Patrol](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=60014-1).

[image]